# Custom domain for "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"

Tags: amazon-cognito

I have a Cognito app client configured to use USER_PASSWORD_AUTH flow. By POSTing this request:

```
{
    "AuthParameters": {
        "USERNAME": "{{Username}}",
        "PASSWORD": "{{Password}}"
    },
    "AuthFlow": "USER_PASSWORD_AUTH",
    "ClientId": "{{AppClientId}}"
}
```

to "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com", I am able to successfully authenticate and retrieve JWTs.

I would like to CNAME the URL to be something like "auth.mydomain.com", but when I do that, I get a client certificate validation error. Is there anyway to associate a valid certificate so I can CNAME the URL successfully?

Answer (score 2):

You can configure a custom domain within your Cognito user pool.  That's what we had to do to make this work. Check out this Cognito [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-add-custom-domain.html).  It discuses using the hosted UI stuff, but it should also apply to your scenario where you provide the login UI.